# change the value of component with function

Tags: reactjs

I am kinda new to reactjs I am using the react-dropdown library https://github.com/fraserxu/react-dropdown and I am trying to make a dropdown menu so my user can switch between 2 languages. However, I am not sure how to properly update the new value for language.
Here's my code:

```
const Navbar = () => {

    const languages = [
        {
          code: 'fr',
          name: 'Français',
          country_code: 'fr',
          key : 1
        },
        {
          code: 'en',
          name: 'English',
          country_code: 'gb',
          key: 2
        },
      ]

    const defaultLanguages = languages[0].name;


    const changeLanguage = (e) => {
        console.log(e)    
    }


    return (
        <div className={color ? 'header header-bg' : 'header'}>
           <ul>
               <li>
                    <DropDown options={languages} value={defaultLanguages} onChange={(e) => changeLanguage} />
               </li>
           </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

as you can see I want to switch between french and english but I am not sure how to pass the value to the dropdown component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the same attributes in your options (languages) passed to the Dropdown component. You can see the examples of both flag options and object options on the [official repo](https://github.com/fraserxu/react-dropdown):

```js
//Options

//Flat Array options

const options = [
  'one', 'two', 'three'
];
//Object Array options

const options = [
  { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
  { value: 'two', label: 'Two', className: 'myOptionClassName' },
  {
   type: 'group', name: 'group1', items: [
     { value: 'three', label: 'Three', className: 'myOptionClassName' },
     { value: 'four', label: 'Four' }
   ]
  },
  {
   type: 'group', name: 'group2', items: [
     { value: 'five', label: 'Five' },
     { value: 'six', label: 'Six' }
   ]
  }
];
```

Below code worked on my side:

```html
import Dropdown from 'react-dropdown';

const Navbar = () => {
  const languages = [
    {
      value: 'fr',
      label: 'Français',
    },
    {
      value: 'en',
      label: 'English',
      country_code: 'gb',
    },
  ];

  const defaultLanguages = languages[0].label;

  const changeLanguage = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
  };

  return (
    <div className={'header'}>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Dropdown
            options={languages}
            value={defaultLanguages}
            onChange={changeLanguage}
          />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MreR.png)

Comment: could you accept my answer? I'm a beginner on StackOverflow need Reputation :D

Answer (score 0):

Create local state for tracking currently selected language. Also move out languages array outside of component. Here is the code:

```js
    const languages = [
        {
          code: 'fr',
          name: 'Français',
          country_code: 'fr',
          key : 1
        },
        {
          code: 'en',
          name: 'English',
          country_code: 'gb',
          key: 2
        },
      ]

const Navbar = () => {

  const [selectedLanguage, setSelectedLanguage] = useState(languages[0].name);


    const changeLanguage = (option) => {
           setSelectedLanguage(option.name)
    }


    return (
        <div className={color ? 'header header-bg' : 'header'}>
           <ul>
               <li>
                    <DropDown options={languages} value={selectedLanguage} onChange={changeLanguage} />
               </li>
           </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this but I am getting an error when I click on my dropdown menu: Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {code, name, country_code, key}).

Comment: I looked up the api of your library. options should string literals or [
  { value: string, label: string }] format. So you should refactor your languages array.

Comment: ye I changed it and it's fixed thanks. Answer above helped me